# Nonzero Symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that a 2-dimensional subspace of the space of $2\times2$ matrices contains a non-zero symmetric matrix.

I don't know if it should be written like the addition of two symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix or there is another way to show it.

Comment: A two-dimensional subspace contains two arbitrary linearly independent $2\times 2$ matrices (ie not scalar multiples). Show that you can take a linear combination of two such matrices to get something nonzero and symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Take any two linearly independent matrices in the subspace:

$\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1\\ c_1 & d_1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2\\ c_2 & d_2\end{pmatrix}$

If $b_1=c_1$ or $b_2=c_2$, then we are done. So assume $b_1\ne c_1$ and $b_2\ne c_2$. Now take the following linear combination (which must be in the subspace):
$(c_2-b_2)\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1\\ c_1 & d_1\end{pmatrix}+(b_1-c_1)\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2\\ c_2 & d_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x & b_1c_2-b_2c_1\\ b_1c_2-b_2c_1 & y\end{pmatrix}$ where $x=a_1(c_2-b_2)+a_2(b_1-c_1),y=d_1(c_2-b_2)+d_2(b_1-c_1)$.

It is clearly symmetric, so we are done provided at least one of $x,y,b_1c_2-b_2c_1$ is non-zero. If $b_1c_2-b_2c_1=0$ then $b_1:b_2=c_1:c_2$. wlog we can assume $b_1=\lambda b_2,c_1=\lambda c_2$. If also $x=0$ then $a_1=\lambda a_2$. If also $y=0$, then $d_1=\lambda d_2$ and so the first matrix is $\lambda$ times the second, contradicting independence. So $x,y,b_1c_2-b_2c_1$ are not all zero and we have found a nonzero symmetric matrix in the subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the space of $2\times 2$ matrices is $4$-dimensional.

Note further that the subspace of symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices is $3$-dimensional

---

Now... suppose otherwise that your $2$-dimensional space does not contain any non-zero symmetric matrices.  It follows then that by taking a basis for your subspace and extending it by taking a basis for the subspace of symmetric matrices, that you will have five linearly independent matrices.  (*Make sure you understand why*)

This is, however, a contradiction since it is impossible to find a number of linearly independent vectors from a vector space than the dimension of that space.

---

In general, if you have a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ and two subspaces $A,B$ of dimensions $a,b$ respectively such that $a+b>n$ then you will necessarily have $A\cap B\supsetneq \{0\}$ and have some nontrivial intersection between the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is the linear subspace in question then we can write $V$ as 
$$
V = \{ \lambda_1A + \lambda_2B : \lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
for two linearly independent matrices $A \text{ and }B$. An element of $V$ is symmetric if an only if 
$$
\lambda_1A_{1,2} + \lambda_2B_{1,2} = \lambda_1A_{2,1} + \lambda_2B_{2,1}
\iff
\begin{pmatrix} A_{1,2} & B_{1,2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2  \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} A_{2,1} & B_{2,1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2  \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\iff
\begin{pmatrix} A_{1,2}-A_{2,1} & B_{1,2}-B_{2,1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2  \end{pmatrix} = 0
$$
There must be a non zero solution \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2  \end{pmatrix} to the equation above since the matrix \begin{pmatrix} A_{1,2}-A_{2,1} & B_{1,2}-B_{2,1} \end{pmatrix} can't be 1-1(it is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$). The fact that the solution vector is non zero implies that the resultant symmetric matrix $\lambda_1A+\lambda_2B$ is non zero since $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

In general,  I think I can write like the following
If A,B are two 2×2 matrices , then 
Transpose of (A+B) = Transpose of A + Transpose of B , so it us closed under addition. Then, for any scalar k , Transpose of (kA) = k . Transpose of A = k.A , showing that it is closed under scalar multiplication. 
Thus, both conditions of subspace are hold.

Comment: You are answering your own question. But is it what you were asking?